# How to update a chart taking by querying a database?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, json, chart.js

I'm trying to plot a graph which depicts the number of people issued with a pass in the last 07 days.

I'm using PHP in the backend with `phpMyAdmin's MySQL DBServer`.
For plotting the graph, I'm using `chart.js` (I'm open to suggestions of different libraries for a suitable solution as I just happened to stumble upon this one)

The PHP code for creating a resultant data set for use in `chart.js` JS code is as below:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "xyz";
    $password = "xyz";
    $dbname = "xyz";
    try 
    {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT inDate, COUNT(insertionId) AS occurrence FROM guestvisitorpassdetails GROUP BY inDate"); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $json_inDate = [];
        $json_occurrence = [];
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            extract($row);
            $json_inDate = $inDate;
            $json_occurrence = (int)$occurrence;
        }
        echo json_encode($json_inDate);
        echo json_encode($json_occurrence);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null; 
?>
```

This, below, is the element used to plot the graph

```
<canvas class="my-4 w-100 chartjs-render-monitor" id="myChart" width="1271" height="536" style="display: block; width: 1271px; height: 536px;"></canvas>
```

This, below, is the necessary chart.js script for plotting the graph

```
<script>
    (function () {
        'use strict'
        feather.replace()
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart')
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: <?php echo json_encode($json_inDate); ?>,
                datasets: [{
                    data: <?php echo json_encode($json_occurrence); ?>,
                    lineTension: 0,
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    borderColor: '#007bff',
                    borderWidth: 4,
                    pointBackgroundColor: '#007bff'
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: false
                        }
                    }]
                },
                legend: {
                    display: false
                }
            }
        })
    }())
</script>
```

While the graph plots well with static data, if I try to update it dynamically on each page load by querying the database and updating the plot values, it doesn't work.
I'd be glad if someone could help me with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question as I found a solution to it lately.

There was a minor error in the while loop, being referred below

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    extract($row);
    $json_inDate = $inDate;
    $json_occurrence = (int)$occurrence;
}
```

The values from database being read should be stored into `$json_inDate[]` and `$json_occurrence[]` and NOT `$json_inDate` and `$json_occurrence`. Very minor error done in the thick of time. The code works perfectly fine with these amendments.

Regards and thanks.

Comment: So you're the one who answered, deleted their answer and downvoted my question as well. I posted that comment on my question for you only.

Comment: I did not down vote..! You did not see so I deleted my ans...I don't why you didn't see

Comment: Sir as I mentioned in my comment I work on an airgapped network. I posted the question and then was..deployed somewhere. I couldn't have seen your answer. I received the notification when I came back online about your answer but when I came here to see it there was none. The question is 5 days old, my answer is 2 days old, which again matches my deployment time and why you "wait for 2 days" and I still couldn't see the answer. Anyways, I'll remove my answer and do my part. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Request please acknowledge the comment so that you also know my side of the story and we don't have any bad feelings in between. Post that I'll remove my answer and tick yours as the right one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196748/discussion-between-shivendra-singh-and-shubham-mehta).